# Is symmetric difference (XOR) commutative?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a problem:

**If A, B, C, and D are sets, does it follow that (A $\oplus$ B) $\oplus$ (C $\oplus$ D) = (A $\oplus$ C) $\oplus$ (B $\oplus$ D)?**

How does one approach something like this? I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Below I use the symbols $P\oplus Q\equiv(P\vee Q)\wedge\neg(P\wedge Q)$ for the propositional XOR function and $A\,\triangle\,B=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$ for the symmetric difference operator.)

It follows immediately if you know that the regular binary XOR function $P\oplus Q$ is associative and commutative, since $x\in A\,\triangle\,B$ iff $(x\in A)\oplus (x\in B)$. If you don't know that XOR is associative and commutative, you can see it by recognizing it as the same as addition mod 2, where true is 1 and false is 0.

To show how it applies directly to your example:

$$\begin{align}
x\in(A\,\triangle\,B)\,\triangle\,(C\,\triangle\,D)&\iff x\in A\,\triangle\,B\oplus x\in C\,\triangle\,D\\
&\iff (x\in A\oplus x\in B)\oplus (x\in C\oplus x\in D)\\
&\iff (x\in A\oplus x\in C)\oplus (x\in B\oplus x\in D)\\
&\iff x\in A\,\triangle\,C\oplus x\in B\,\triangle\,D\\
&\iff x\in(A\,\triangle\,C)\,\triangle\,(B\,\triangle\,D)\end{align}$$

I am applying associativity and commutativity of XOR in the third step.

Comment: What does the symbol ⊻ mean?

Comment: @Bob That's the binary XOR function; i.e. it acts on two propositions and is true if exactly one of the two propositions is true. The first sentence was meant to define the symbol.

Comment: Isn't ⊕ the symbol for XOR?

Comment: @Bob I purposely chose a different symbol than $\oplus$ here because the OP chose to use that to denote the symmetric set difference operator, and as Newb stresses, the two operations are different (they act on different spaces). If you prefer, you can replace $\oplus\mapsto\Delta$ and $\veebar\mapsto\oplus$ instead.

Comment: If we're talking about only sets here, then why are we using logical operators? I am still very confused.

Comment: @Bob I changed the notation to match common convention, as suggested in my previous comment. As for why we are using logical operators, the point is that there is a natural correspondence between logical operators and set operators; the transition between them is made by considering the predicate $x\in A$ for your set. Set equality corresponds to equivalence of predicates; thus $A=B$ and $x\in A\iff x\in B$ *by definition* have the same meaning. Set union corresponds to the OR function, since $x\in A\cup B$ iff $x\in A\vee x\in B$, and complementation is the negation operation (con't)

Comment: (con't) since $x\in A^c$ iff $\neg(x\in A)$. Set intersection is the AND function, and in this exact same manner symmetric difference corresponds to the XOR function - $x\in A\,\triangle\,B$ iff $x\in A\oplus x\in B$. Thus all properties like commutativity and associativity map straight over from the logical operators to the related set operators, as they are "equivalent" (more precisely, they both form boolean algebras).

Comment: So, if we convert △ to ⊕, and recognize the fact that ⊕ is associative and commutative, we can rearrange the expression accordingly to find an equivalent?

Isn't △ associative and commutative? Is re-writing it in terms of ⊕ even necessary?

Comment: @Bob I just realized that you are the OP, so I should point out one thing that may be confusing you: the original question should be stated as "does $(A\,\triangle\,B)\,\triangle\,(C\,\triangle\,D)= (A\,\triangle\,C)\,\triangle\,(B\,\triangle\,D)$?", not with $\oplus$, if you adhere to the notational conventions which I have described, since we are talking about the symmetric difference operation on sets $\triangle$, not the XOR operation on logical formulas $\oplus$. My proof converts this statement to one about XOR, which we already know is assoc. and comm.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the symmetric difference is commutative. However, **Symmetric Difference is not XOR.** The two are similar, but they are by no means the same. XOR is a logical operation, Symmetric Difference is an operation you apply to sets.

There are several ways to attack it.

I denote symmetric difference with $\Delta$. Take $A\Delta B$ and $B \Delta A$. Can you show that the two sets are equal? You can show that two sets are equal by showing that they are subsets of each other: if whenever $x \in X, x \in Y$, then $X \subseteq Y$, and then if $Y \subseteq X$, the two sets must be equal.

You could also just consider all the possible cases: $a \in A, a \notin B$, etc. and see if the cases for both sets always work out to be the same.

Comment: How can AΔB and BΔA be equal? If x is a member of A, then it can't be a member of B by definition?

Comment: If you identify sets with their characteristic functions, as in most applications of symmetric difference, there is no distinction between symmetric difference and pointwise XOR. Or if you want to think of XOR as operating on propositions, then identify the set $A$ with the relation $x \in A$.

Comment: @Bob: $A\mathbin{\triangle}B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$, and $B\mathbin{\triangle}A=(B\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus B)$; these are clearly equal.

Comment: @Bob The operation you are thinking of when you say "if $x \in A$, then $x\notin B$" is Set Difference. We are talking about the Symmetric Difference here.

Comment: @ronno: What you’ve just said is that if you pretend that two different things are the same thing, then there is no difference between them. This simply isn’t so. Despite the obvious relationship between them, symmetric difference and exclusive or are not the same thing.

Comment: @ronno To add to what Brian said, if you do not assume the law of excluded middle in logic then the obvious correspondence between subsets of $X$ and functions $X \to \{0,1\}$ can break down.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was just trying to point out that there is a (often useful) correspondence between subsets of $X$ and functions $X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ so that symmetric difference corresponds to XOR. You think of them as two different things, I consider them to be two different ways of looking at the same thing.

Comment: How would showing that AΔB=BΔA help show the relationship in the question is true?

Comment: @ronno: It isn’t a matter of *considering* them different things: they *are* different things. That there is a useful natural correponsdence between them does not change this fact, and you do the OP no favors by misleading him on this point. Students (as a group) have a hard enough time learning to use mathematical language precisely.

Comment: @Bob: Because $A\triangle B = B\triangle A$ is the definition of commutativity for symmetric difference. Are you thinking of associativity?

Comment: @TrevorWilson My knowledge about constructive mathematics is very limited, and if you do not assume excluded middle, then I am not sure what a function from $X \to \{0,1\}$ really means. Can we not still identify $x \in A$ with $1_A(x)=1$ and $\lnot(x \in A)$ with $1_A(x) =0$?

Comment: @Newb Yes, I am. I need to prove that I can rearrange those sets accordingly.

Comment: @ronno I don't know much about it either, but I think the point is that constructively a function $X \to \{0,1\}$ is something you can _prove_ always takes one value or the other, whereas for a subset of $A \subset X$ there may be some $x \in X$ such that you can't prove or disprove whether $x \in A$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\oplus$ operation is commutative, since
$$P\oplus Q \iff \hbox{Exactly one of $P$, $Q$ is true}.$$
This formulation is symmetric in $P$ and $Q$.

The $\oplus$ operation is associative since
$$(P\oplus Q)\oplus R \iff \hbox{An odd number of $P$, $Q$ and $R$ is true},$$
and since this formulation is symmetric in the three arguments.